# Loading into Pandas dataframe from bytes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, azure-data-lake-gen2

All,

I'm trying to load a file that is in **Azure Datalake Storage GenV2** into a **Pandas DataFrame** and I'm unable to get the below working. I get the error **"No Columns to parse from file"**

What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from io import BytesIO

credential =  InteractiveBrowserCredential()

# Get the below details from your storage account
storage_account_name = "premodel"
container_name = "analyticsworkspace"
directory_name = "pythontest"

#will use Azure AD Integrated connection
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https", storage_account_name), credential=credential)  
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system=container_name)
dir_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(directory_name)

file_name = "AdultCensusIncome.csv"
file_client = dir_client.get_file_client(file_name)

download = file_client.download_file()
downloaded_bytes = download.readall()

data = BytesIO(downloaded_bytes)
csvfile = pd.read_csv(data)

csvfile.count()
```

Comment: Can you post, say, the first ten lines of AdultCensusIncome.csv? I think there may be something strange in that file.

Comment: age, workclass, fnlwgt, education, education-num, marital-status, occupation, relationship, race, sex, capital-gain, capital-loss, hours-per-week, native-country, income
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K
38, Private, 215646, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Handlers-cleaners, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K

Comment: Here is the file :   https://code.datasciencedojo.com/sirawitta/tutorials/raw/af4fe336ad50db4b49dcca126875acb2ab138f05/Datasets/AdultCensusIncome.csv